CORS issue error on Ruby on Rails with Coolify and Caddy as Proxy
I have hosted React Frontend app as a client on Coolify and hosted a Rails Backend api app as a server with PostgresSQL and Redis on Coolify as well. It's working fine locally but not working on production and uat environments on coolify. Can anyone please help me? Do I need some kind of Proxy adjustment or sth else? I have been stuck here for a week now. I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you so much!
Server CORS config
Client Axios request
I have twisted the CORS config and also the Proxy of the Caddyfile. But I am not going anywhere.
I am also getting this message in Proxy logs every 5 seconds.
2024-11-24T14:00:25.043139001Z {"level":"info","ts":1732456825.0429814,"logger":"docker-proxy","msg":"Process Caddyfile","logs":"[ERROR]  Removing invalid block: parsing caddyfile tokens for 'handle_path': path matcher must begin with '/', got http://uat.api.meritbox.me*, at Caddyfile:4\n:// {\n\tencode zstd gzip\n\thandle_path http://uat.api.meritbox.me* {\n\t\treverse_proxy 10.0.3.5\n\t}\n\thandle_path http://www.uat.api.meritbox.me* {\n\t\treverse_proxy 10.0.3.5\n\t}\n\thandle_path https://www.uat.api.meritbox.me* {\n\t\treverse_proxy 10.0.3.5\n\t}\n\theader -Server\n\ttry_files {path} /index.html /index.php\n}\n\n"}
2024-11-24T14:00:30.045719445Z {"level":"info","ts":1732456830.045587,"logger":"docker-proxy","msg":"Process Caddyfile","logs":"[ERROR]  Removing invalid block: parsing caddyfile tokens for 'handle_path': path matcher must begin with '/', got http://uat.api.meritbox.me*, at Caddyfile:4\n:// {\n\tencode zstd gzip\n\thandle_path http://uat.api.meritbox.me* {\n\t\treverse_proxy 10.0.3.5\n\t}\n\thandle_path http://www.uat.api.meritbox.me* {\n\t\treverse_proxy 10.0.3.5\n\t}\n\thandle_path https://www.uat.api.meritbox.me* {\n\t\treverse_proxy 10.0.3.5\n\t}\n\theader -Server\n\ttry_files {path} /index.html /index.php\n}\n\n"}

I now got this popup.
Popup
And this is my twisted Caddy config.

networks:
  coolify:
    external: true
services:
  caddy:
    container_name: coolify-proxy
    image: 'lucaslorentz/caddy-docker-proxy:2.8-alpine'
    restart: unless-stopped
    extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
    environment:
      - CADDY_DOCKER_POLLING_INTERVAL=5s
      - CADDY_DOCKER_CADDYFILE_PATH=/dynamic/Caddyfile
    networks:
      - coolify
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '443:443/udp'
    labels:
      - coolify.managed=true
      - coolify.proxy=true
      - "caddy=
        # Production Environment
        api.meritbox.me {
            encode zstd gzip
            handle /* {
                reverse_proxy 10.0.3.2 {
                    header_up Host {upstream_hostport}
                    header_up X-Real-IP {remote_host}
                    header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote_host}
                    header_up X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}
                }
            }
            header {
                Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://meritbox.me
                Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS'
                Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Content-Type, Authorization, access-token, expiry, token-type'
                Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
                Access-Control-Expose-Headers 'access-token, expiry, token-type, Authorization'
                -Server
            }
            try_files {path} /index.html /index.php
        }
        www.api.meritbox.me {
            redir https://api.meritbox.me{uri} permanent
        }
        # UAT Environment
        uat.api.meritbox.me {
            encode zstd gzip
            handle /* {
                reverse_proxy 10.0.3.5 {
                    header_up Host {upstream_hostport}
                    header_up X-Real-IP {remote_host}
                    header_up X-Forwarded-For {remote_host}
                    header_up X-Forwarded-Proto {scheme}
                }
            }
            header {
                Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://uat.meritbox.me
                Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS'
                Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Content-Type, Authorization, access-token, expiry, token-type'
                Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
                Access-Control-Expose-Headers 'access-token, expiry, token-type, Authorization'
                -Server
            }
            try_files {path} /index.html /index.php
        }
        www.uat.api.meritbox.me {
            redir https://uat.api.meritbox.me{uri} permanent
        }"
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
      - '/data/coolify/proxy/caddy/dynamic:/dynamic'
      - '/data/coolify/proxy/caddy/config:/config'
      - '/data/coolify/proxy/caddy/data:/data'

